# How to merge multiple push notification?

Tags: android

My question is that how to merge multiple notification?
Here is my code:

```
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, DemoActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(result))
            .setContentText(result);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(++NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

It gives me every individual notification like windows phone but I can't merge into a notification. So, please give me advice what to implement in this method.

Comment: mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());... Try this..

Comment: Thnks for this... but its overwrite the message but i want  like....."2 message"

Comment: Do you mean like in whatsapp? i.e. 2 messages from user?

Comment: ya bro that's like i want ..